# Can you use await in paperjs?

Tags: async-await, fetch, paperjs

Very simple question, can I use functions like `await` inside paperjs?
I can chain together a lot of `.then`'s and it's going fine, but as soon as I add `await` in front of it I get the error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (4:22)

Please tell me they didn't make it so that I have to start wrapping everything in insanely long chains in order to integrate functions like fetch into paperjs. Below my code:

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">

      getCollectionList = async function() {
           var collectionlist = [];
           collectionlist = await fetch('/api/graph/<%= database %>');
                console.log(collectionlist);
           }

           getCollectionList();

</script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
```

Comment: @ggorlen please find the code in the original post that I edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are writing your code as `PaperScript` which implies that `Paper.j`s uses a `JavaScript` parser to parse it and apply some transformations to it.
The problem is that by default, the `JavaScript` parser used by `Paper.js` does not support `ES6` features.

You have to load a more recent version of the parser (`Acorn`) before loading `Paper.js` to solve your issue.
See my answer to an analog issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58856900/7615922) for more details.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Debug</title>
    <!-- Load latest acron version first -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/acorn"></script>
    <!-- Then load Paper.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/paper"></script>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
          margin: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          height: 100%;
      }

      canvas {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
// Here you can now use ES6 syntax.
const myAsyncFunction = async function() {
    const response = await fetch('https://yesno.wtf/api/');
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
};

myAsyncFunction();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```