# Can paperscript use javascript's classes?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

When I load a script as simple as:

```
class ClassName {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 3;
  }
}
```

into a web page as `text/paperscript`, the web console returns

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:6)

If I switch to `text/javascript` everything runs as intended, meaning there's no syntax error. Ah, and of course I've linked the `paper.js` library in the HTML source.

Why JavaScript classes don't work in paperscript? Isn't paperscript just an extension of JavaScript?

Comment: I would be very surprised to learn that any browser understands the MIME type "text/paperscript" at all. I guess it's possible that a library for that tool would scan the document for `<script>` tags like that.

Comment: A library can register to process such things.  That's how babel works, if used in the browser.  It registers itself as a script handler.  Paperjs does this.  Or is supposed to.

Comment: In PaperJS, it's handled [here](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/0a56c7cef09f614f6c5e540049fa980a1ee78570/src/core/PaperScript.js#L573)

Comment: Are you including the paper.js script before your script?  Are you using the full script, or core?

Comment: @Amy right, that's pretty much exactly what I said :)  Anyway this seems to require that a different JavaScript parser be used, [as mentioned in this Github issue](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1357)

Comment: @Pointy I think what happened was, I started my comment while you were editing your own.

Comment: No worries :)  [Here's another issue](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1183) that describes how to load an updated Acorn version.

Comment: It's kind-of weird that they haven't made the standard distribution use a new parser, that first bug is from 2016.

Comment: I've included the `paper.js` library as the first <script> and I'm using the full script. However, I may not have explained myself correctly: what's happening is that everything works, except for the classes. That said,  I thought it was easier for you to answer and I really don't want to waste your time. So, given that it isn't a priority as for now, I'll try to figure out this myself c:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paperjs causing class syntax error when not using Paperjs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58847325/paperjs-causing-class-syntax-error-when-not-using-paperjs-code)

Comment: It does, thank you!