# paper.js - create array of draggable shapes

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am trying to create a set of shapes in paper.js. Each shape should be draggable and the index of that shape be given during dragging.

I have tried the following code, but I just get the message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined".

Any help gratefully received.

```
<canvas id = "canvas_1" > < /canvas>
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.11/paper-full.min.js" > < /script>

<script type = "text/paperscript" canvas = "canvas_1" >
  var path = [];

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    path[i] = new Path.Circle({
      center: view.center,
      radius: 30,
      fillColor: 'blue'
    });

    path[i].onMouseDrag = function(event) {
      path[i].position += event.delta;
      console.log("shape " + i + " is being dragged.")
    }

  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

Your error comes down to the way [variable scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#block_scoping_rules_with_var_or_function_declaration_in_non-strict_mode) works in Javascript: *variables are scoped to the containing function or script*. By the time you come along and drag the circle, `i === 5` from the for loop, and thus `path[i]` is undefined (out of bounds) in the drag function. Hence, your error.

If you would like to learn more, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29558498/8820824) provides an in-depth look into this "closure inside loop" problem.

## Solutions

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/8820824) provides some common solutions to this problem.

### ES6 Let

The [ES6 `let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is the modern solution to this problem, avoiding many of the scope "quirks" of the `var` statement. *Variables scope to the containing block*, so each pass of the loop gets its own instance of `i`.

To use ES6 features within PaperScript, you first need to [load a newer version of the Acorn parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58856900/8820824) *(thanks sasensi and Geddes)*. Then simply declare `let i` in the loop:

```js
var path = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  path[i] = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 30,
    fillColor: 'blue'
  });
  path[i].onMouseDrag = function(event) {
    path[i].position += event.delta;
    console.log("shape " + i + " is being dragged.")
  };
}
```

[Here is a working Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-paperscript-es6?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.html)

#### Closure

Without modifying the PaperScript parser, you could use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to capture the index in a new function scope:

```js
var path = [];

function createMouseDragHandler(index) {
  return function(event) {
    path[index].position += event.delta;
    console.log("shape " + index + " is being dragged.")
  };
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  path[i] = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 30,
    fillColor: 'blue'
  });
  path[i].onMouseDrag = createMouseDragHandler(i);
}
```

[Here is a working Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-paperscript-closure?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.html)

Comment: Thank you so much - this is perfect.

The reason the [let] keyword is unsupported may be explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58847325/paperjs-causing-class-syntax-error-when-not-using-paperjs-code

Can you explain the solution involving [let] and why it is preferable please?